# Cannot access external drive

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, partition, external-disk, error

I have a seagate 2013 or 2014 external hard drive which has been working fine up until yesterday.  The drive wont appear anywhere on my mac-  not on desktop, finder, disk utility wont ever finish loading when its plugged in.  I've gone into System Information and it appears whether or not the device is installed so not sure what that means.  I have tried a few tips I found to use Terminal- I've tried creating and naming the volume usb and then linking it to dev/disk 2 but nothing.  It will however let me eject the device via terminal which I hope is a good sign? I ran diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk2 and i got the following:  "Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting.  Error: -69854: A disk with a mount point is required." I've read that I probably need to do something that would wipe out all the information on my external but first I would need to back up.  As I said before, I can't access my drive on any macs (i've tried 2 others) so is my next step to send it out for someone to recover the data?  I'm just trying to save myself some money because I'm currently furloughed but I do need the documents on my external.  Any advice would be great! I'm not knowledgable on any of this, I've just been doing alot of searching and trying different tips so please leave advices fit for a computer dummy! ha! Thanks!

Comment: I think the first thing I'd try is the `Disk Utility` app. If you've never used it, here's how to find it: click your `Launchpad`, then click the folder labeled `Other`. When that folder opens, you'll see an icon labeled `Disk Utility`. Make sure your external HDD is plugged in, and then start (click) the `Disk Utility` app. When `Disk Utility` opens, check if it shows an `External Drive`. Take a screenshot of the `DiskUtility` screen, and add that to your question via the `edit` feature. Let us know if any of that's not clear.

Comment: Here's [something that may be of interest](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/repair-a-storage-device-dskutl1040/mac) to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get the [free app Mountain](https://appgineers.de/mountain/) and see if it will mount the drive. Often when I've had troubles mounting a drive Mountain helped. The app has a free trail so it'll cost you nothing. Start the app from the menubar and it lists all the Volumes connected to your computer. Find the drive tyou want and click the mount  icon.